# Big O of union method of dynamic connectivity problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

i faced a paradox to analyse this function, Why the time complexity of this function is N^2 and not N?

```java
public void union(int a, int b) {
        int aid = ids[a];
        int bid = ids[b];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (ids[i] == aid) {
                ids[i] = bid;
            }
        }
    }
```

Its an implementation of eager approach, to solve dynamic connectivity problem , complete code is:

```java
// Union method has N^2 time complexity!!
class EagerApproach extends UnionFind {


    protected int[] ids;

    EagerApproach(int[] input) {
        super(input);
        ids = new int[input.length];
        System.arraycopy(input, 0, ids, 0, input.length);
    }


    public boolean connected(int a, int b) {
        return ids[a] == ids[b];
    }

    public void union(int a, int b) {
        int aid = ids[a];
        int bid = ids[b];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (ids[i] == aid) {
                ids[i] = bid;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: The complexity of this method is `O(N)` where `N = ids.length`. How did you define `N`? How is `ids` defined?

Comment: what is ids? where tdoes it come from? the function is O(n), however if the access operation of ids is O(n) it becomes O(n^2), this would be the case if ids is a list

Comment: It certainly looks `O(N)` to me, where `N` is the size of the `ids` array.  Who told you that the answer is `O(N^2)` ?

Comment: ids are array with length N

Comment: Is the array access `ids[x]` in constant time `O(1)` (as its typically in most programming languages)? Or is it linear `O(n)` like in a linked list for example?

Comment: @Zabuzard it's an implementation of "EagerApproach" in Dynamic Connectivity problem.

Comment: That does not really answer my question.

Comment: Yes, in java array accesses costs o(1).

Comment: Either you misread the source or it's wrong. One possible mistake is that the source makes some statement about the complexity of multiple union operations on some number of objects and you've interpreted it as a statement of the complexity of a single union operation on the objects. Can you provide a reference to the source material? Eg: name of book or online resource

Comment: For example, Sedgewick, Algorithms in Java says "The quick-find algorithm executes at least MN instructions to solve a connectivity problem with N objects that
involves M union operations. For each of the M union operations, we iterate the for loop N times. Each iteration requires at least one instruction (if
only to check whether the loop is finished)"

Comment: @PaulHankin The source I am studying is "Corsera Algorithms, By Robert Sedgwick", To my knowledge, the union method should have a complexity of O(n) right?.

Comment: Yes, the `update` method has `O(n)` complexity. But the source maybe did not claim anything different and only said that some algorithm that uses this method multiple times has `O(n^2)`. We can not really guess without seeing the exact quote of the claim you are refering to.

Comment: From that coursera course, in the video lecture on "Quick Find" the slide at 06:50 says "Takes N^2 array accesses to process N union commands on N objects". https://www.coursera.org/lecture/algorithms-part1/quick-find-EcF3P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your array access `ids[x]` is in constant time `O(1)`, the time complexity of the `union` method is **linear in the length of the array** `ids`. So

```
O(ids.length)
```

or `O(n)` if we define `n` as `ids.length`.

---

Be careful with the definition of `n` and `ids` though. If, in your specific application, `n` was defined as `ids.length = n * n`, then this is obviously `O(n^2)` with `n` being `sqrt(ids.length)`.

Comment: we do not know the definition of ids, maybe the elemnt access is O(n)

Comment: @zpasztor True, I thought this is a Java question in which case `ids` has to be an array with constant time access. Answer edited.

Comment: I added the complete code, to disambiguation.

Comment: @smarteist That did not help since we do not know what programming language this is, Java? In Java array access is in constant time.

Comment: @Zabuzard yes, its java and costs constant time for array accesses, But according to the source I am studying, the union method costs O(n^2 ), but i didn't know why?!

Comment: @smarteist I doubt that they claim that. Mind adding a quote of the section to the question? You probably misunderstood it.